# Getting a year from a 4-digit number in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, date, datetime, excel-2013

I have a list with two columns Year and Month. The Year column is populated by 4 digit numbers (e.g. 1997,2006) while the Month column is populated by Strings (January, February, etc.).

I am trying to make a 3rd column which makes a date out of the Year and Month colum with the day date fixed at 15. So a row with 1997 and January becomes 15/01/1997 (in UK format).

I have used `=DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(B2&1),DAY(15))` as a formula but this changes the date to 15/01/1905. I know that Excel uses a serial number format for dates but is there a way to turn a 4 digit number into a year-date?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [DATEVALUE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEVALUE-function-b5bd5892-0c18-4c78-be4a-d7b5b3525e23) as,

```
=datevalue(B2&" 15, "&A2)
```

Months (e.g. *January, February, etc*) in column B and years (e.g. *1997, 2006,  etc*) in column A.

Format the column with the formula as one of the Date type number formats.

Comment: fwiw, one of the problems you are having is that **2015** is already a year and you are trying to get the YEAR from a year. Dates are **1** for every day past 31-Dec-1899 so as a Date, **2015** is actually 07-Jul-1905. When you ask for the YEAR(2015), you are getting back **1905**. You just needed to use `=DATE(2015, ...` not `=DATE(YEAR(2015), ...` but there were going to be problems converting *January* to a **1** in any event.

Comment: fwiw², your original formula would have worked as `=DATE(A2, MONTH(B2&" 1"), 15)`. See  [DATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATE-function-B91BEF00-4B5B-4EE0-B80E-06E68B1DFF29)

Comment: Thanks Jeeped, =DATE(A2, MONTH(B2&" 1"), 15) worked perfectly. Thanks again